# Trying to create a rotating spinner wheel in Java

Tags: java, processing

I am currently working on a small project where I'm creating a simple boardgame-like spinning wheel. The user will press a button and the spinner will randomly land on one of the four colors (red, green, yellow, or blue). The trouble I'm having is getting the spinner to rotate in a circle (or clockwise) and randomly land in a random position in one of the four squares.

[Screenshot of game thus far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDNyR.png)

And source code:

```
void setup() { // this is run once
  size(800, 800);
}

void draw() { //  this is run repeatedly
  background(255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  fill(255,0,0);
  rect(100,100,300,300);
  fill(0,96,255);
  rect(100, 400, 300, 300);
  fill(255,240,0);
  rect(400, 100, 300, 300);
  fill(0,255,0);
  rect(400, 400, 300, 300);

  // how to rotate this part like a spinner?
  strokeWeight(20);
  line(400, 400, 400, 600);
}
```

I then need to figure out how to determine which color the spinner landed on, and print out text that says "You have landed on [the color the spinner lands on]". I am having difficulty understanding the Matrix aspect of determining the coordinates after the rotation.

I am coding in Java in the Processing development platform.

Comment: That last part of your problem about determining where the spinner lands may be the most complicated step, at least in the solution I proposed. I'm not going to be able to solve it right now, but here's an article that approaches the idea: https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/return-actual-coordinates-after-translate-and-rotate.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, working with both circles and coordinates can be a little tricky in programming. You're going to have to do some conversion between Polar and Cartesian coordinates.
[Here's a great reference to the difference between the two.](https://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html)

So you'll need to first generate a random number between 0 and 2 PI (Radians), this is done easily in processing:
`float rnd = random(0, TWO_PI);`

Next need let's convert it to normal coordinates:

```
 float x = 200 * cos(rnd);
 float y = 200 * sin(rnd);
```

Lastly draw the line: `line(400, 400, x + 400, y + 400);`

Edit: Forgot processing had `rotate()`, that'd be a much better solution than this mess

Answer (score 0):

Your first step will be to learn about rotations that are isolated to one shape without rotating the entire sketch. There's a code pattern involving `pushMatrix`, `popMatrix`, `translate`, and `rotate` - all in conjunction with one another.

```
// inside draw
pushMatrix();
translate(400, 400);
rotate(radians(rotation));
line(0, 0, 100, 100);
popMatrix();

rotation += 5;
```

The `translate` function moves the origin to a new position, in this case 400, 400. Any shapes drawn after the origin moves are relative to it. That is the reason line is drawn at 0, 0 on the new origin which is actually 400, 400. The functions `pushMatrix` and `popMatrix` isolate this code so as not to affect the rest of your sketch. It's a nice trick to create independent rotations (and anything else really) in your sketch without having to come up with math formulas to counteract all your movements. Imagine five spinners going different speeds and directions.

For a gradually slowing spinner, I introduce a `stepSize` variable and slowly decrease it and subtract it from rotation until rotation hits zero and the spinner stops.

```
// still inside draw
if (stepSize > 0) {
  rotation += stepSize;
  stepSize -= 0.05; // play around with this value
}
```

Here's a demo program putting all the pieces together to achieve a spinner that will move for a while then stop.

```
float rotation = 1, stepSize = 10;

void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(100, 100, 300, 300);
  fill(0, 96, 255);
  rect(100, 400, 300, 300);
  fill(255, 240, 0);
  rect(400, 100, 300, 300);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(400, 400, 300, 300);
  strokeWeight(20);

  pushMatrix();
  translate(400, 400);
  rotate(radians(rotation));
  line(0, 0, 100, 100);
  popMatrix();

  if (stepSize > 0) {
    rotation += stepSize;
    stepSize -= 0.05; // play around with this value
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  stepSize = random(5,15); // try adjusting these values
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the value of 'r'? I do not see a variable anywhere that had r as it's name

Comment: Sorry about that - I rewrote this a few times and ended up changing the value of `r` to `rotation` in the code. It's the value of the current rotation used inside push/pop matrix.

Comment: I see, but where would you decrease rotation? In a loop?

Comment: Instead of a fixed rotation speed and a stop limit counter, I use a stepSize variable and allow the rotation to slow down to a stop. See updated demo above.